# How to draw very tiny loops in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, graphs

[image]I am trying to draw the Brujin Graph D(2,3) in such a way that it no edges cross, but the loops on {0}{11}{22} are causing me problems. Is there a way to make the loops very small using this format? Kind regards.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tkz-graph}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \SetGraphUnit{4}
      \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal]


                          
      \Vertices{circle}{00,01,11,12,22,20}
      \Edges[style = ->](00,01,11,12,22,20,00)
      \SetGraphUnit{1.5}
      \Vertices{circle}{10,21,02}
      \Edges[style = ->](10,02,21,10)
      \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style= {->, bend left}}
      \Edges[style = ->](01,10,01)
      \Edges[style = ->](02,20,02)
      \Edges[style = ->](21,12,21)
      \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style= {->, bend right = 100}}
      
      \Edges[style = ->](12,20,01,12)
      \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style= {->}}
      \Edges[style = ->](21,11,10)
      \Edges[style = ->](02,22,21)
      \Edges[style = ->](10,00,02)
      \Loop[style = {->}, dir = NO](00)
      \Loop[style = {->}](11)
      \Loop[style = {->}](22)
    
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \caption{De Brujin}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is currently incomplete and uncompileable. So at least I have no idea what you have so far, what you are trying to achive and what the picture above shows.

Comment: Excuse me for the miss-understanding I updated the code. The code gives the graph depicted in the image. What I need to do is modify the section with \Loop or \Edges[style = ->](12,20,01,12) in such a manner that they don't overlap.

Comment: Side note: you misspelled "De Bruijn" (first the i, then the j).

Comment: There seems to be a dedicated tikz-based package, adigraph, for that purpose: https://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/adigraph/adigraph_documentation.pdf // Find a kind of gallery with code and graphs here; overread the German text ;) https://www.namsu.de/Extra/pakete/Adigraph.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `loop`s from the always loaded [`topaths` library](https://tikz.dev/library-edges#sec-74.4) has relatively small loops which look nice, in my opinion.

I've extended these to also allow the four missing compass directions above right, above left, below left and below right. As well as a general `Loop` key that takes the direction as an angle (`loop right` would be `loop = 0`).

For placing the nodes I'm using the `graphs(.standard)` libraries. which provide the `graph` syntax as well as the `subgraph C_n`.

Connecting the nodes is also done via the `graphs` syntax.

For the big arrows between 01, 20 and 12 I'm setting the `looseness` to 2 and the relative angle to `50`. It makes for much sharper curves that fit right around the nodes between.

The [`bbox` library](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-bbox) is used for these big curves so that the bounding box is correctly evaluated and the picture isn't bigger than it needed to be.

The loops are small enough in this case by their own but I've added dashed duplicates where these loops could have also been placed.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard, arrows.meta, bending, bbox}
\tikzset{
  Loop/.style={anchor={#1+180}, out={#1+15}, in={#1-15}, loop},
  /utils/temp/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{loop #1/.style={#1,out={#2},in={#3},loop}},
  /utils/temp/.list={above right:60:30, above left:150:120,
                     below left:240:210, below right:300:270},
  every new ->/.append style={shorten >=+3\pgflinewidth},
  every new <-/.append style={shorten <=+3\pgflinewidth}}
\begin{document}
\tikz[> = {Stealth[round]}]
  \graph[
    nodes = {draw, circle},
    clockwise, phase = 0, radius = 1.5cm,
    chain polar shift=(0:2cm)
  ]{% -!- makes it so that the second subgraph is considered a chain
    subgraph C_n[->, V={10, 02, 21}] -!-
    subgraph C_n[<-, V={00, 20, 22, 12, 11, 01}],
    {[cycle, ->] 02, 22, 21, 11, 10, 00},
    {[/tikz/bend left=15, ->, every group/.append style=cycle]
      {10, 01}, {02, 20}, {12, 21}
    },
    00 ->[loop right     ] 00,
    11 ->[loop above left] 11,
    22 ->[loop below left] 22,
    {[edge=dashed] % as an option
      00 ->[Loop = 150] 00,
      11 ->[loop below] 11,
      22 ->[Loop = 30 ] 22
    },
    {[/tikz/bend right=50, /tikz/looseness=2, /pgf/bezier bounding  box, ->, cycle]
      01, 12, 20
    }
  };
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: cou you tell me how to rotate the subgraph C_n[->, V={10, 02, 21}]  60 degrees?

Comment: @Dedekid Add `phase = 60` to its options: `subgraph C_n[->, V={10, 02, 21}, phase = 60]`.

Comment: Thank you very much.