# Joining vertices of polyhedra

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to join each vertex of the 5-gone with the opposite to the current joined vertex of the 10-gone. See the picture (colors have to be black):
[image]

So far I have the following, but two vertices are not connected correctly.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}    % For reducing margin
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=10, minimum size=4cm, draw=black, shape border rotate=20, name=x] at (6,6) {};
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5, minimum size=1.5cm, draw=black, name=y] at (6,6) {};

\foreach \corner in {1,2,...,10}
\node[circle,ball color=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt] at (x.corner \corner){};

\foreach \corner in {1,2,...,5}
\node[circle,ball color=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt] at (y.corner \corner){};

\draw foreach[
  evaluate={\cornerA=int(2*\c);
            \cornerB=int(\cornerA-1);}] \c in {1,...,5}{
              (x.corner \cornerB) -- (y.corner \c)
              };
              
\draw foreach[
  evaluate={\cornerA=int(2*\c);
            \cornerB=int(\cornerA+4);}] \c in {1,...,5}{
              (x.corner \cornerB) -- (y.corner \c)
              };

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: It's not quite clear to me which vertices you want to connect. The opposite ones on the bigger polygon? Do you want to rotate the bigger one so that the connections don't cross the inner vertices?

Comment: Each vertex of the 5-gone has to be connected with two vertices of the 10-gone. One is already connected. Now I need to connect one more with the opposite vertex of  the one already connected (like in the picture above). It's ok if the edges cross at one point in the middle as I clearly show where the vertices are. I am not sure if the rotated version will look better.

Comment: But if the rotation will make it look better (clearer), I'd appreciate if you show it to me. Thank you!

Comment: I tried to add \draw foreach[
  evaluate={\cornerA=int(2*\c);
            \cornerB=int(\cornerA+4);}] \c in {1,...,5}{
              (x.corner \cornerB) -- (y.corner \c)
              };    but it doesn't connect it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes to your original code:

- Rotating the outer polygon by 18° (180°/10) not 20°.
- Using `outer sep = 0pt` for the polygons so that the corners actually lie at the specified diameter.
- Naming the ball nodes so that they can be used as such, this will make the edges stop at their border and not draw over them.
- The opposite corner is evaluated by the `mod` function, usually this would be `<corner opposite> = mod(<corner>+5, 10)` if the corners would be numbered from 0 to 9 but since they are numbered 1 to 5 we only add 4 inside the Mod function and one outside of it.

I've also added a similar drawing via the `graphs` library, this is very close to [another recent answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/686496/16595), I'm using the same foreach evaluation to draw the diagonal edges.

I've drawn them with the double function in red and black to visualize that they do not cross the whole diagram but stop at the inner balls.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard, shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  rp/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides={#1}, outer sep=+0pt},
  ball/.style={
    circle, outer sep=auto, ball color=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=5pt}
]
\node[rp=10, minimum size=4cm,   draw=black, rotate=18, name=outer] at (6,6) {};
\node[rp=5,  minimum size=1.5cm, draw=black, name=inner] at (6,6) {};

\foreach \corner in {1,2,...,10}
  \node[ball] (outer-corner-\corner) at (outer.corner \corner){};
\foreach \corner in {1,2,...,5}
  \node[ball] (inner-corner-\corner) at (inner.corner \corner){};

\foreach[evaluate={
  \cOuter=int(2*\cInner-1);
  \cOpposite=int(mod(\cOuter+4,10)+1);
}]\cInner in {1,...,5}
  \draw (outer-corner-\cOuter)
     -- (inner-corner-\cInner)
     -- (outer-corner-\cOpposite);
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikz\graph[
  nodes={
    circle, outer sep=+0pt, ball color=black, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+5pt},
  counterclockwise, phase = 90, typeset =,
]{
  subgraph C_n[name=inner, n= 5] -!-
  subgraph C_n[name=outer, n=10],
  { [edge={double=black, red, thick}]
    \foreach[evaluate={
      \cOuter=int(2*\cInner-1);
      \cOpposite=int(mod(\cOuter+4,10)+1);
      }] \cInner in {1,...,5} {
        inner \cInner -- {outer \cOuter, outer \cOpposite}},
  }
};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

While we find a more automatic solution, here you have a manual one:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}    % For reducing margin
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=10, minimum size=4cm, draw=black, shape border rotate=20, name=x] at (6,6) {};
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5, minimum size=1.5cm, draw=black, name=y] at (6,6) {};

\foreach \corner in {1,2,...,10}
\node[circle,ball color=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt] at (x.corner \corner){};

\foreach \corner in {1,2,...,5}
\node[circle,ball color=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt] at (y.corner \corner){};

%\draw foreach[
%  evaluate={\cornerA=int(2*\c);
%            \cornerB=int(\cornerA-1);
%            \cornerC=int(mod(\cornerB+5,10);}] \c in {1,...,5}{
%              (x.corner \cornerB) -- (y.corner \c) -- (x.corner \cornerC)
%              };

\draw foreach \a/\b/\c in {1/1/6, 2/3/8, 3/5/10, 4/7/2, 5/9/4}
    {(x.corner \b)--(y.corner \a)--(x.corner \c)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Update:*

This code applies the rotation correction proposed by Qrrbrbirlbel and an automatic way for computing vertices connections. This connection is still drawn stopping at pentagon vertices.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}    % For reducing margin
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=10, minimum size=4cm, draw=black, shape border rotate=18, name=x] at (6,6) {};
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5, minimum size=1.5cm, draw=black, name=y] at (6,6) {};

\foreach \corner in {1,2,...,10}
\node[circle,ball color=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt] at (x.corner \corner){};

\foreach \corner in {1,2,...,5}
\node[circle,ball color=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt] at (y.corner \corner){};

\draw foreach[
  evaluate={\cornerA=int(2*\c);
            \cornerB=int(\cornerA-1);
            \cornerC=ifthenelse(\cornerB+5>10, int(mod(\cornerB+5,10)), int(\cornerB+5));}] \c in {1,...,5}{
              (x.corner \cornerB) -- (y.corner \c) -- (x.corner \cornerC)
              };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to make them intersect exactly at one point in the middle?

Comment: @Vika A new version applying rotation correction and automatic computing has been added.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed!